How to Re-encrypt an Existing Dexie-encrypted Database with a New Key
I am using Dexie.js with the dexie-encrypted library to encrypt my IndexedDB database in a web application. The encryption key is derived from a user token that changes every hour or so, requiring me to re-encrypt the existing data with the new key to be able to access it when I lose the old key.
How can I efficiently re-encrypt the data with the new key without causing memory issues?
